# app.use requires a middleware function getting error

Tags: node.js, regex, express

```
//imports
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const errors = require('./middleware/errors');

//static port for run server
const PORT = 3000;

//mongo connection
mongoose
.connect('mongodb+srv://devkeyurkasvala:@cluster0.xqdxmvf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connected to Database Successfully');
}   )
.catch((e) => {
    console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB', e);
    }   );

//getting error here for app use function please help me with this its my proper code
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api", require("./routes/app.routes"));
app.use(errors.errorHandler);


//connecting server
app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port: ${PORT}`);
  }   );
```

This is my code for a Flutter application. Basically this is api and I am getting error while run server on localhost. I am getting error that saying app.use() requires a middleware function. What is the fix for this?

This is my GitHub repo if you want full code: https://github.com/KKasvala/kitchen_server_flutter

Comment: Does your `./routes/app.routes` expose anything via `exports`?

Comment: yes module.exports = router

Comment: Try commenting out your` app.use` statements until it at least boots, then enable them selectively until it fails. One of yours is not quite set up right.

Answer (score 1):

Error appears on this line: `app.use(errors.errorHandler);`
You export as `default errorHandler` from ./middleware/errors, so in this file `const errors` is equal to `errorHandler` inside ./middleware/errors. You just have to do following: `app.use(errors)`

Make your code look like this:

```
  const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    // now we importing errorHandler
    const errors = require('./middleware/errors');
    const router = require("./routes/app.routes");
    
    //static port for run server
    const PORT = 3000;
    
    //mongo connection
    mongoose
    .connect('mongodb+srv://devkeyurkasvala:@cluster0.xqdxmvf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Connected to Database Successfully');
    }   )
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB', e);
        }   );
    
    //getting error here for app use function please help me with this its my proper code
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use("/api", router);
    app.use(errors);
    
    
    //connecting server
    app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
      console.log(`Server listening on port: ${PORT}`);
    });
```

Comment: Adding a text explanation at the beginning of the answer that describes what the problem was and what you did to fix it would make this a better answer.  As it stands now, we have to somehow do a visual diff to try to figure out what you changed and there's no explanation for why you did that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Hope it's look better now.